# Flash AS3 How to Create a Preloader for Internal Events

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, dynamic, movieclip, preloader

Alright, there is a problem occurring in one of the scenes of my flash project.

That part creates MovieClip functional buttons, places them, and resizes (character) MovieClips as an added graphic on the "Button."

It seems very clear it is a loading problem because if I click one of the "MovieClip" buttons as soon as I get on that scene, I get an error on one of the properties, but if I wait a second, it is just fine.

The scene loads and creates all the buttons and such without any lag and instantly looks fine, even the mouseover.

This is kind of a strange problem, everything loads and flows just fine, it is just this one part that if I click any of them immediately I get the error (doesn't crash the .swf either.)

Any ideas on what I can do about this?

Thanks.

Comment: hm, that does sounds very strange. What's the error it gives out?

Comment: That a property was undefined. With the MovieClip "buttons", I had set my own property to it, buttonEnemyID. I found out the problem was with the mouse listener on the "button" that when I clicked on one of them ASAP. I found the solution. It was actually because of a default value: var enemyID = 0;. I don't know why, but  I always have so much trouble with declaring values like that. Took away the equals zero, and the problem went away. -Sorry my explanation is probably confusing.